# Find MAX in Column Range ignoring Error values using Evaluate Syntax

Tags: excel, vba, range, max, array-formulas

I have defined a range called **`Rng`**. The `Columns(2)` of `Rng` contains numbers and #N/A error values. I want to find the MAX value in this column and then compare if it is `>0`.

```
Col A    Col B
--------------
ansdlsd  1
sdlsds   1
lgdfkf   2
fdlksd   2
sdlsdks  3
sds sds  5
sdlkjq   #N/A
eowmf    #N/A
pwpwo    #N/A
qwdds    #N/A
ospw     #N/A
dlsls    #N/A
qpdmf    #N/A
```

I tried using the shorthand syntax for `Application.Evaluate` i.e. `[]`, but the code returns a Type Mismatch Error 13 - (Error 2029 in Watch Window).

```
If [MAX(IF(NOT(ISNA(Rng.Columns(2))),Rng.Columns(2)))] > 0 Then
    do something...
End If
```

I also tried :

```
If Application.Aggregate(4, 6, Rng.Columns(2), 1) > 0 Then...
```

got error `: Error 2015 : Variant/Error`.

[image]

I am able to get the MAX using the Excel `Array Formula (Ctrl+Shft+Entr)` in a worksheet:

```
{=MAX(IF(NOT(ISNA(B2:B14)),B2:B14))}
```

I suppose it has to do with the `Rng.Columns(2)` not being evaluated correctly by the `[]` brackets.

Or is something else the cause of this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub GetMax()

Dim rng As Range, lr As Long
With Sheet1 'Change accordingly
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("A1:B" & lr)
    If Application.Aggregate(4, 6, rng.columns(2)) > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Max is higher than 0"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Max is not higher than 0"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

If you want to use `.Evaluate` you can change this line: `If Application.Aggregate(4, 6, rng.columns(2)) > 0 Then`, for this: `If .Evaluate("AGGREGATE(4,6," & rng.Columns(2).Address & ")") > 0 Then`

The reason this works is that we can utilize `MAX` within the [`AGGREGATE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df) function and tell it to ignore error values.

---

***Why did your attempts not succeed:***

The reason your attempt with `[]` failed is because you cannot use these brackets to evaluate a formula with variables. You'll need to actually use `Application.Evaluate`. Secondly, you'll need to feed the formula the actual address. I've implemented the `.Evaluate` version in my answer above.

The reason your attempt with `AGGREGATE` raised an error is because you needed to omit the last parameter within the `MAX` function of `AGGREGATE`. If you would try it on a worksheet, it would also raise a `#VALUE` error. You simply don't need to input a index number since `MAX`, as the name suggests, returns just one value.

Comment: @sifar, the code I have put up works for me. About your edit, you just needed to omit the last parameter within the `AGGREGATE`

Answer (score 2):

for those who have old ms excel version (<2010) that not supports `AGGREGATE` worksheetfunction:

```
Sub GetMax_oldstyle()
    Dim rng$, lr As Long
    With Sheet1 'Change accordingly
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        rng = .Range("A1:B" & lr).Columns(2).Address(0, 0)
        If .Evaluate("MAX(IF(NOT(ISNA(" & rng & "))," & rng & "))") > 0 Then
            Debug.Print "Max is higher than 0"
        Else
            Debug.Print "Max is not higher than 0"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

test:

[image]

Comment: You just need a dot `.` in front of `Evaluate` in case another sheet has been selected when you run your code :)